# how to modify the information in package.xml

Tags: ros, package.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am newer in ROS. I am learning the method of creating the catkin package. And when I go to the step of customizing the package.xml tag. the problem occurred. How to make modification of the xml file in terminal?  cat package.xml just can read this file but not write or edit. Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276198/how-to-modify-the-information-in-package.xml/) by [tairos](https://answers.ros.org/users/32670/tairos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use a text editor?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tairos](https://answers.ros.org/users/32670/tairos/) on 2017-11-18**:
oh yes, I install vim to edit the documents. Thanks a lot.